# How do I remove this typescript error in a javascript file?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a typescript error in a javascript file

[image]

- It's a folder with only one javascript file, no nodejs or package.json.
- I disabled the typescript extensions (tslint was not installed)
- I checked my visual code settings JSON:

  ```json
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",   
  "[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" }
  ```
- I disabled or installed prettier, but didn't change it
- I have typescript Version 4.4.2 installed globally

Comment: try to disable https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#checkJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (windows) or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (os x) to open command panel. Type `Preferences: Open Settings(UI)` to go to settings. (You can do the same with `Preferences: Open Settings(JSON)` if you want)

Search `JavaScript: Validate` and disable it. Like shown in the image

[image: enable/disable JS validation]

Comment: Genius, this works

Comment: @ObaApi If you think this answer helped you, please consider [upvoting and accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). I see your profile, and you do not seem to accept or upvote answers, this will discourage users to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: I've upvoted! Thanks

Comment: @ObaApi As the asker, you have special privilege to mark an answer "correct" if it solves your problem. [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157936). You should consider accepting other answers from the past because none of them seem to have an accepted answer.